# Increment and Decrement Counters not Setting State Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple component that will act as a counter! There are two counters, one for counting repetitions, and another for counting amounts lifted. For some reason, the functions that I write are not working as intended.

The expected result is, when I click on the up or down arrow for say, reps, it should update THAT number in the state. Same goes for the amount lifted.

But what's happening is, when I click the up and down arrow for let's say, reps again, it works and increments and decrements correctly, but when I then click the arrows to increment and decrement the amount lifted, NaN is returned and then if I click on the rep arrows after that, that too then returns NaN.

Here's my relevant code:

```
class TrackProgress extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.id),
      exercise: [],
      trackProgress: {
        exercise_id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.id),
        date: "",
        reps: 0,
        amountLifted: 0
      }
    };
  }

  handleChanges = e => {
    this.setState({
      trackProgress: {
        ...this.state.trackProgress,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  repsIncrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      trackProgress: {
        reps: this.state.trackProgress.reps + 1
      }
    });
  };

  repsDecrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      trackProgress: {
        reps: this.state.trackProgress.reps - 1
      }
    });
  };

  amountLiftedIncrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      trackProgress: {
        amountLifted: this.state.trackProgress.amountLifted + 1
      }
    });
  };

  amountLiftedDecrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      trackProgress: {
        amountLifted: this.state.trackProgress.amountLifted - 1
      }
    });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div className="track-progress-container">
        <div className="track-progress-content">
          <div className="heading">
            <h1>Start Tracking</h1>
            <h2>{this.state.exercise.exerciseTitle}</h2>
          </div>
          <form className="tracking-form-container" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <div className="rep-lift-flex">
              <div>
                <h6>REPS</h6>
                <input
                  name="reps"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="OO"
                  value={this.state.trackProgress.reps}
                  onChange={this.handleChanges}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <h6>LIFTED</h6>
                <input
                  name="amountLifted"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="OO"
                  value={this.state.trackProgress.amountLifted}
                  onChange={this.handleChanges}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="arrow-container">
              <div className="rep-arrows">
                <img
                  src={down}
                  alt="decrease"
                  name="decrementReps"
                  className={
                    this.state.trackProgress.reps === 0 ? "inactive" : ""
                  }
                  onClick={this.repsDecrease}
                />
                <img
                  src={up}
                  alt="increase"
                  name="incrementReps"
                  onClick={this.repsIncrease}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="lift-arrows">
                <img
                  src={down}
                  alt="decrease"
                  name="decrementLifted"
                  onClick={this.amountLiftedDecrease}
                  className={
                    this.state.trackProgress.amountLifted === 0
                      ? "inactive"
                      : ""
                  }
                />
                <img
                  src={up}
                  alt="increase"
                  name="incrementLifted"
                  onClick={this.amountLiftedIncrease}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <h6>Date</h6>
            <input
              name="date"
              type="date"
              placeholder="e.g. June 11, 2019"
              value={this.state.trackProgress.date}
              onChange={this.handleChanges}
              className="date"
            />
            <button type="submit" className="track-btn">
              TRACK EXERCISE
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackProgress;
```

Here's were my initial functions before I wrote out more specific function. They both produced the same results.

```
reps = event => {
    if (event.target.name === "incrementReps") {
      this.setState({
        trackProgress: {
          reps: this.state.trackProgress.reps + 1
        }
      });
    } else if (event.target.name === "decrementReps") {
      this.setState({
        trackProgress: {
          reps: this.state.trackProgress.reps - 1
        }
      });
    }
  };

  amountLifted = event => {
    if (event.target.name === "incrementLifted") {
      this.setState({
        trackProgress: {
          amountLifted: this.state.trackProgress.amountLifted + 1
        }
      });
    } else if (event.target.name === "decrementLifted") {
      this.setState({
        trackProgress: {
          amountLifted: this.state.trackProgress.amountLifted - 1
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

I could be missing crucial logic or not account for something, I've been staring at this for hours, so help solving this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the whole trackProgress object when you update either reps or amount lifted. Your state is:

```
this.state = {
     id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.id),
     exercise: [],
     trackProgress: {
         exercise_id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.id),
         date: "",
         reps: 0,
         amountLifted: 0
     }
}
```

Calling your update function for reps or currently replaces the entire trackProgress object, instead of just updating the properties you want.

```
repsIncrease = () => {
    this.setState({
        trackProgress: {
            reps: this.state.trackProgress.reps + 1
        }
    });
};
```

Leads to:

```
state = {
     id: 1,
     exercise: [],
     trackProgress: {
         reps: 1,
     }
}
```

To fix this, you can include all the previous properties in your repsIncrease/decrease function, or use the spread operator to automatically fill them out. Here's an example of the fixed repsIncrease function.

```
repsIncrease = () => {
    this.setState({
        trackProgress: {
            ...this.state.trackProgress,
            reps: this.state.trackProgress.reps + 1
        }
    });
};
```